# How to hide robot.txt from vistors?

Tags: seo

I have seen sites hide the robot.txt file.

if you enter the name of the site as
**http://www.mysite.com/robot.txt** 
you will not receive the robot.txt,

I also want to hide the file robot.txt from visitors how to do it?

Is there a connection of these lines

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOODP">
         <meta name="Slurp" content="NOYDIR">
```

So I do not understand the meaning of the code.
Thank you!

Comment: If you hide your robots.txt then search engines won't see it, what's the point?

Comment: Also, a quick search found descriptions of the meta tags above: http://www.metatags.org/meta_name_slurp

Comment: Well [SO certainly doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt). And they seem pretty good in terms of user-experience and SEO, so I can't see this being a benefit to you or your site, can you explain why you'd want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but couldn't you do that with URL rewrites? You might be able to display the robots.txt file for visitors with the User Agent strings of a crawler (for instance, "Googlebot"), and then redirect to a 404 if it's a non-crawler UA